# Using MULTI with multiple redis-cli

Tags: redis

What is the use of using MULTI and EXEC in one client if the other client can still edit the key?

Redis-cli 1:
multi
set name ABC

Redis-cli 2:
set name XYZ

Redis-cli 1:
exec

The final value of name becomes ABC

So what was the point of using multi in redis-cli 1 when redis-cli 2 could still change while transaction in redis-cli 1 is still going on?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, i.e. running single command with multi-exec, you cannot get any benefit. Even worse, multi-exec hurts performance, since you need to send 3 commands to Redis.

Multi-exec is used to run several commands in a transaction, although commands from other clients might mix with multi-exec commands.

```
client 1: multi
client 1: set key value
client 2: set key new-value
client 1: set key2 another-value
client 1: exec
```

Redis won't run commands from client 1 until it receives `exec`. So Redis runs these command with the following order:

1. Redis receives MULTI command from client 1, and begin to queue commands from client 1
2. Redis runs command from client 2, i.e. set key new-value
3. Redis receives EXEC command, and runs all command between MULTI and EXEC from client 1.

Comment: The question was what's the point of using MULTI/EXEC by client1? Why couldn't client1 just run its commands without MULTI/EXEC?

Comment: Check the first paragraph of my answer. In your case, it's a bad idea to use MULTI/EXEC

Comment: In what case will it be a good idea to use MULTI EXEC? Even if client1 had 10 operations to do (instead of 1), what benefit does MULTI/EXEC bring?

Comment: Check the second paragraph of my answer. If you need transaction, you can use MULTI/EXEC. However, Lua scripting is a better choice for transaction.

Comment: It just explains what is MULTI/EXEC used for, it doesn't explain why it needs to be used? Or what is the benefit of using it.

Comment: It queues the commands sequentially without interruptions. I.e. you can call a 'config set appendfsync always' then change a key/value and set 'appendfsync no' to save aof if you have aof off by default. If you did not use multi in this case, aof will start for all changes.

Answer (score 0):

`MULTI` solves two problems.

First, it allows you to execute things atomically. You can queue up several commands and then they run all at once:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> SET foo bar
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> SET baz qux
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> EXEC
1) OK
2) OK
```

This will set `foo` and `baz` at the point that `EXEC` is called. If something else changes `foo` or `baz` while the commands are being queued but before `EXEC` is called, then these changes will be overridden.

Note that to do this, the keys need to be on the same shard. If you are running in a clustered environment there are additional considerations. But that's another, and somewhat bigger topic.

The other use for `MULTI` is for optimistic locking using the `WATCH` commands. You can watch a field and if someone else changes is during the transaction, the transaction will fail.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> WATCH foo
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> SET foo bar
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> EXEC
(nil)
```

This will set `foo`  at the point that `EXEC` is called. If something else changes `foo` while the commands are being queued but before `EXEC` is called, then the queued commands will not be executed and `EXEC` will return `(nil)`.